# Using tymon/jwt-auth function instead of laravel default

Tags: laravel, jwt

How do i actually use the login function in AuthController which generate the JWT token with laravel blade? Because right now the blade is using the default laravel login function which just redirect the user to home page without generating token. Most tutorials just show how it works with postman.

**AuthController**

```
   public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);

}
```

**Api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group([

'middleware' => 'api',
'prefix' => 'auth'

], function () {

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

**Web.php**

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) didn't help?

Comment: @kerbholz the doc didnt teach how to use with laravel login blade